# Android Room Database

Tags: java, android, sql, android-room

I can't wrap my head around how should i get my data without much boilerplate.

The problem:
I have a database that i cannot alter.  Which has multiple field of same type almost same for example i have text_en and text_fr (both are the same word in different language English and French) and i got + 71 same field but different languages.

What I need is something like

```
@Entitiy(tableName = "blabla")
class X {

    private String textTarget;
    private String textMain;

    ...
}
```

How should I do my Dao interface to get desired language and map into x class

what should work is to update entity `ColumnInfo(name ="text_en")` for example.

```
@Query("select  :main , :target from phrases where :id ")
    List<X> getPhrase(String main,String target);


usage : getPhrase("text_en","text_esp");
   // for example returning object X with field main = "hello" and target " holla")
```

The above example return the following error:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
```

Comment: do you want getPhrase method to return your custom type object ?

Comment: what is `text_target` and `text_main`? it isn't quite clear for me. Please provide a sample of invocation of this method and the desired result (e.g. `getPhrase("hello", "text_spain")` -> X{text_target = "hola", text_main="hello"}

Comment: Yes,The Entity class cannot map the "text_de" for example into textTarget
And  i cannot change the Entity ColumInfo name according to match my query criteria

Comment: okay, but how the word to be translated is specified here? or out task is to get ALL the words that have translations in the table from the target language to destination?

Comment: I would imagine this like `getPhrase(String currentLanguage, String languageToTranslateInto, String wordToTranslate)`

Comment: @AndreyIlyunin updated the usage : 
No i would search by id. Example ( i dont know what  will be the texts  nor the main or target) 
Get the text wher id = 10 and return me the transaltion in english and spanish as i entered in the parameters [ getPhrase("text_en","text_esp",10); ]

and if i would like text in french and chinese [ getPhrase("text_fr","text_zh",10);

Answer (score 0):

What you put in @Query is an SQL-statement, you can actually test them in sqlite command line utility or any desktop software to verify their correctness. So if you want a translation to the desired language, it should look like this:

```
@Query("SELECT :main AS text_main, :target AS text_target FROM `phrases` WHERE id = :id)
List<Translation> getTranslationById(String firstLang, String secondLang, long id);
```

Where Translation should be something like this:

```
class Translation {
    @ColumnInfo("text_main")
    String main;
    @ColumnInfo("text_target")
    String target;

    //setters, getters, etc
}
```

This class is used only as a return value from the method.

Comment: The problem is that in my db  i don't have "text_main" i have "text_" + language code. So the @ColumnInfo("text_main") will not work

I have more then 70+ language codes..

Comment: please read carefully: `SELECT :main AS text_main, :target AS text_target FROM 'phrases'`